# how to delete last printed line in python

Tags: python

how to delete last printed line in python
for example

```
s = 'abc'
for c in s:
    print(c)
```

it get

```
a
b
c
```

I want

```
a
b
```

Is there any way except `s[:-1]` or `if c!= 'c'` or it is the only way to get the answer

The method of using two ANSI escape codes `LINE_UP = '\033[1A' LINE_CLEAR = '\x1b[2K'` is not success

Comment: The RIGHT answer is not to print it in the first place.